# Android Studio - video reward works but there's no more callback - possible glitch?

Tags: android-studio, callback, admob-rewardedvideoad

I'm experiencing a frustrating problem with the video callback for rewarded videos. 
Until yesterday, it worked just perfectly fine on every device virtual or real (except my 2012 Nexus7).

Now the video still loads, plays but then nothing. I didn't edit my code. I tried backups up to a week without any luck. Worst, somehow now the old build I had installed on my Nexus7 gets a successful callback yet the backup from that build doesn't have callbacks on any other device.

Tried updating anything I could, wiping cache, restarting everything but no change.

Is it a glitch on google side? I've stumbled onto [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/BxsfiCtVlfc) while searching.

My code for that part is basically standard copy pasted admob template and the reward is in "onRewardedVideoCompleted".

EDIT: "onRewarded" works though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from a Google forum staffer. It's -still- an issue on their side (see link in my original question).